# Why does my React component rerender automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, use-effect

I have a simple React component and when I inspect the console what I logged appears 3 times.

The `Load APP` log comes from my main `App.js` component and `Load New` from the component rendered by the Navigation in `App.js` : `FasList.js`.

Why do I see 3 logs when I only log one time in my component ?

[image: Log output]

I did a second test with a log in a `useEffect` :

[image: Second Log output with useEffect]

Here is the code in `App.hjs` :

```js
    console.log('APP');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAuthStatus();
        console.log("I'm in useEffect");
    }, []);
```

Does the log output repeating itself have something to do with the way React works ?

According to the second test, the component only renders 1 times but still 3 `APP`log

Here is a working example of the problem with my 2 components :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/logs-output-demo

Comment: Can you include the related code? Like the components which have been mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Also, please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the state 1 more time with `fetchAuthStatus()` method, so a re-render happens. This does not mean that the DOM is changed twice. I think your code is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The body of your component function runs every time the component gets rendered. Your component get rendered any time React thinks that's necessary, but typically once when initially added to the page and then again whenever its state changes. (Several state changes done at the same time typically only result in a single render, but if there's any gap between them, rendering will happen after each.)

Code in a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook callback runs after rendering the first time, and then again any time one of the dependencies you list changes. Since your code isn't listing any dependencies, the hook callback only runs once.

Here's a simple example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

    // Runs after initial render, then again every time `flag` changes
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect #1 ran, flag = ${flag}`);
    }, [flag]);

    // Runs after initial render, then every time `flag` or
    // `counter` changes
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect #2 ran, flag = ${flag}, counter = ${counter}`);
    }, [flag, counter]);
    
    // Runs after initial render only
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect #3 ran`);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Increment" onClick={() => setCounter(c => c + 1)} />
            <input type="button" value="Flip Flag" onClick={() => setFlag(f => !f)} />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You may find [this article by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) useful. It goes into depth about how React renders, in the context of explaining `useEffect` (but it's a useful read even separate from understanding `useEffect`).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I just understood the reason why I had 3 logs it's was because I have two states changing (my `authStatus` and then `isLoading`) so that makes 3 rerender of my component

Comment: @A.Ecrubit - Yeah. It depends on when you do them (whether you do the first and then do the second in an asynchronous callback or similar). If it were literally `setAuthStatus(a); setIsLoading(false);` you'd only get one state change rendering call. But if they're separated in time, you'll get two.